# Having problems with computing two-sided limtis

Tags: limits

I am having problems calculating sided limits. I understand what a sided limit is (both graphically and analytically), but I'm having problems calculating them and I really need advice.

Here's an example:

$f(x) = \frac{x^2-2x}{(x^3-3x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$

WolframAlpha returns that the left limit is $\infty$, and that the right limit is $-\infty$. But, when I try to calculate them, I get the opposite results.

For example, if I simply try to "plug in $0_{+}$, I get this:

$$\frac{ (0_{+})^2 - 2\cdot0_{+}}{(0_{+})^3 -3\cdot (0_{+})^3)^{\frac{2}{3}} }$$

I'm not quite sure how to calculate this. I'm not even sure if it can be done by simply plugging in the value. I'd really appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this example and give advice on how to calculate them generally speaking.

Answer (score 1):

You have to state in what intervals is positive
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-2x}{(x^3-3x^2)^{2/3}}$$
Denominator is positive for any $x$ so the function is positive where the
numerator is positive, that is, in $(-\infty,0)\cup(2,+\infty)$

$$\underset{x\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\;f(x)=-\infty$$
because for $x>0$ the function is negative

$$\underset{x\to 0^-}{\text{lim}}\;f(x)=+\infty$$

Therefore the limit at $x=0$ doesn't exist, while the limit at $x=3$ is $+\infty$ from both directions.